# Test to check if array is reversed in place

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a method which I have put on the array prototype that reverses the array (this is done for learning purposes only). This method should reverse the array in place.

```js
Array.prototype.yarra = function () {
  for (let left=0, right=this.length-1; left<right; left++, right--) {
     [this[left], this[right]] = [this[right], this[left]]
   }
   return this
};
```

I have written some tests to check if the method works as expected.

```js
describe('yarra', function () {
  it('should reverse an array in place and return it', function () {
    var arr = [1,2,3];
    var reversedArr = arr.yarra();
    reversedArr.should.eql([3,2,1]);
    arr.should.equal.reversedArr;
    [4,5,6].yarra().should.eql([6,5,4]);
  });
});
```

I realise the tests don't work as expected as I reversed the array out of place and returned a new array, and it still passed. Also, because `var reversedArr = arr.yarra()` means arr will always equal reversedArr, so it doesn't really check for anything.

How would I write a test that can check if the array is reversed in place?

Comment: Why can't you use arr.slice().yarra() and compare that instead? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ibowankenobi .slice would create a new array, so it wouldn't be possible to compare `arr.should.equal.arr.slice().yarra()`, was that what you meant?

Comment: I wanted you to create a new copy on purpose otherwise reversed and the old would always be the same array since they are the same object. Because in your question you said it doesn't really do anything yourself. One thing I can think of is to stringify them with JSON.stringify and compare the strings.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const assert = require('assert');


Array.prototype.yarra = function () {
    for (let left=0, right=this.length-1; left<right; left++, right--) {
       [this[left], this[right]] = [this[right], this[left]]
     }
     return this
  };

  describe('yarra1', () => {
    it('should reverse an array in place and return it', () => {
      let arr = [1,2,3];
      let rev = [3,2,1];
      let reversedArr = arr.yarra();
      for(let i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
        assert(reversedArr[i]===rev[i])
      }
    });
  });

  describe('yarra2', () => {
    it('should reverse an array in place and return it', () => {
      let arr = [1,2,3];
      let rev = [3,2,1];
      let reversedArr = arr.yarra();
      assert(reversedArr.toString() === rev.toString())
    });
  });
```